# how to run javascript function before c# method gets executed

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am facing this issue form last couple of days... expert advice needed...

I am trying to read query string value from URL in code behind. if the query string is available then i need to geocode it. and the function for that is on the same .aspx page.

that function will get the geocode(LAT,LNG) from google and assign it to the hidden variable available on the page. after that i need to run my c# code which then gets the LAT,LNG values and goes into database to find the nearest stores.

## Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _queryStringVal = Request.QueryString["k"];
    string eventTarget = Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
    string eventArgument = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_queryStringVal))
      {
        qsText.Value = _queryStringVal;
        BindListView();
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArgument) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(eventTarget))
      {
        Lat = Convert.ToDouble(eventTarget);
        Long = Convert.ToDouble(eventArgument);
        BindListView();
      }
    }
}

protected void BindListView()
{
    var parameter = _queryStringVal;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter))
    {
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Alert", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('hello');</script>", true);
      //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "GeoCodeAddress", "codeAddress(" + qsText.Value + ");", true);
    }

    Lat = Convert.ToDouble(currentLat.Value); // this is where error occurs because the value is NULL
    Long = Convert.ToDouble(currentLong.Value);

  if ((Lat == 0.00) || Long == 0.00)
    {
          ShowErrorPanel();
          return;
    }
}
```

as you can see simple alert is also not displayed when the page is loaded with querystring param.

i need to run the `codeAddress(param)` function before the c# attempts to assign Lat, Long values.

Please help.

## EDIT

when the query string value is not present, page is displayed with the text box. when user hits button, through javascript i am redirecting to the same page without querystring and it works fine. I need querystring for my homepgae. i have a general search box on the page in which if you enter postcode or town, it will redirect it to the stroes page with querysting and shows the nearest stores. so thats why i need querysting to work..

## JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var param = getParameterByName("k"); // function to get querystring param
    if (param.length > 1) {
          codeAddress(param);
    }
});

function codeAddress(addressToGeoCode) {
    var geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addressToGeoCode }, function (results, status) {
      if (status == window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var firstLoc = results[0].geometry.location;
            lathv.val(firstLoc.lat());
            lnghv.val(firstLoc.lng());
            PageRedirect();
      }
      else {
            console.log('No results found: ' + status);
      }
    });
}

function PageRedirect() {
    //window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "?k=" + $('.AddressSearch').val();
   __doPostBack(lathv.val(), lnghv.val());
}
```

Comment: You have mixed responsibilities. Your server-side code is tightly coupled to your client side code.. in that they are attempting to perform the same function at the same time. You should move your server side code into a web service of some description, and perform the rest of the work client side (interacting with the service).

Comment: have you tried using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock instead of ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript.

Comment: @Simon: can you give me some example...

Comment: @Neelam: i have tried that with no luck...

Comment: Have you tried using : Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( GetType(), "GeoCodeAddress", "codeAddress(" + qsText.Value + ");", true);

Comment: @Sam: i have tried that....not working...

Comment: @patel.milanb  You can't run Client side script beore protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e).

See Darin Dimitrov answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546452/how-to-execute-jquery-script-before-page-load